# get particular attr from a html string in php

Tags: php, html

i have a punch of links in a string like following

```
<link  type="image/png" href="http://infinitewp.com/wp-content/themes/mystile-child/images/favicon.png" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://infinitewp.com/wp-content/themes/mystile-child/images/favicon.png" />

<link  type="image/png" href="http://infinitewp.com/wp-content/themes/mystile-child/images/favicon.png" />
```

i need to get `href` for which link has the `rel="shortcut icon"`
i can find shortcut icon link using

```
 strpos($content,"shortcut icon")
```

this code but i need to get the href of this link? how to do this in easy way?

Comment: have you though of using jquery to get the href of required link

Comment: Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) and xpath. They make it TRIVIAL to find something in an html doc. Doing string operations is just too painful.

Comment: using `jquery`? @xenish can you please give some tips how?

Comment: what do you want to do after you grab the value@ThamaraiselvamThangavel

Comment: need to store it ! first i need to get that href @xenish

Comment: well depends because if you use jquery you will need ajax and php to store the value in database . var mydata = $('link [rel = "shortcut icon"]').attr('href'); this code can get the href value then using ajax you will need to post data and then store it in database. @ThamaraiselvamThangavel

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "Your URL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
$xml->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$arr = $xpath->query('//link[@rel="shortcut icon"]');

echo $arr[0]['href']; // This is the content of your href.
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\m\index.php on line 103` gives error dude

Comment: Then your $html is not a valid XML (this is why we added DOMDocument in my last answer).

Comment: I've edited my answer, to change simpleXML to DomDocument. This class is less strict about valid XML.

Comment: Almost - query is a method of `DOMXPath` rather than `DOMDocument` ... just need to add something like `$xPath = new DOMXPath($xml);` then change `$xml->query(...);` to `$xPath->query(...);` You can probably also bullet all the `curl` stuff and just use `$xml->loadHTMLFile()`.

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMElement as array` gives error